# Find the probabilty of 25 random people

Tags: probability

X is the weight of one person, $X \sim N(\mu =78,\sigma =13.15 )$.

If I choose randomly 25 people, what is the probability that the average of their weights will be $86$ ?

I define $\displaystyle Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = \frac{X-78}{13.15}$ and now $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(X>86) = 1- \mathbb{P}(X<86) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(Z< \frac{86-78}{13.15}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(Z<0.6) = 1- \Theta(0.6) = 0.28$.

But, how can I calculate the average weights of 25 random people ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability will be zero, since $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=0$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ when $Y$ is a continuous random variable, and the normalized sum of independent normal random variables (i.e. the average of independent Gaussians), is a continuous random variable.

If we define $Y= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{25} \frac{X_i}{25}$ to be the average of the weights of the 25 people, we can however find a non-zero value for $$\mathbb{P}(Y \le 86)$$ which technically is different than what the question asks for $\mathbb{P}(Y=86)=0$.

Anyway, when we say that we choose 25 people "randomly", I assume that to mean that the weight of all of the people are assumed to be independent. This has the benefit that it allows us to have a simple form for the sum of normal random variables (i.e. because they are independent).

Specifically, the sum of the $X_i$ should be distributed as $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(25 \cdot 78, 5 \cdot 13.15)$$

(see for example: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables))

Now, normalizing by $25$, (i.e. dividing by 25, since $Y=\frac{1}{25} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i$) we get that $$Y \sim \mathcal{N}(78, \frac{13.15}{5})$$ Since the mean of $nY=\sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i$ is $n \mu$, but the mean of $Y=\frac{n\mu}{n}=\mu$, and the standard deviation of $nY$ is $\sqrt{n}\sigma$ since the variance is $n\sigma^2$ (because it is the sum of 25 copies of $X$, which has variance $\sigma^2$), and then the standard deviation of $Y=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot nY$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n \sigma^2}= \sqrt{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ (See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables)).

Therefore $\mathbb{P}(Y \le 86)=\mathbb{P}(Z < \frac{5(86-78)}{13.5})$.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean "normalizing by $25$" ?

Comment: what I mean is dividing by 25, since $Y=\frac{1}{25} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i$

Answer (score 3):

Let the weights of our people be $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$, where $n=25$. Then the average weight $\bar{X}$ is given by
$$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots +X_n).$$
Under our assumptions, $\bar{X}$ has normal distribution, mean $\mu$, and standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. In our case the mean of $\bar{X}$ is $78$, and the standard deviation is $\frac{13.15}{5}$.

Now you can compute any probability you wish, in the usual way. Note that the probability that $\bar{X}$ is *exactly* $86$ is in principle $0$.  But if what you are interested in is $\Pr(\bar{X}\gt 86)$, that is done in the style you used in your calculation, the only thing that changes is that instead of standard deviation $13.15$ we use standard deviation $\frac{13.15}{5}$.

Comment: Can you explain why the  standard deviation is  $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ ?
And why the mean is not $n\mu $ ?

Comment: The mean of $n\bar{X}=\sum_{i=1}^{25} X_i$ is $n \mu$, but the mean of $\bar{X}=\frac{n\mu}{n}=\mu$

Comment: The standard deviation of $n\bar{X}=\sqrt{n}\sigma$ since the variance is $n\sigma^2$, and then the standard deviation of $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n\bar{X}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n \sigma^2}= \sqrt{\sigma^2}{n}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: $X\sim N(\mu _{X},\sigma _{X}^{2})$  , $Y\sim N(\mu _{Y},\sigma _{Y}^{2})$ 
$Z=X+Y $ $\Rightarrow  {\displaystyle Z\sim N(\mu _{X}+\mu _{Y},\sigma _{X}^{2}+\sigma _{Y}^{2}).}$

Comment: So, why the mean of $\bar{X}$ is not $n\mu$ ?

Comment: @Noam: Sorry, was away. William has given a thorough explanation. The **sum** has mean $n\mu$, variance $n\sigma^2$. But when we then divide by $n$ to get the sample mean $\bar{X}$, we multiply $n\mu$ by $1/n$, and $n\sigma^2$ by $(1/n)^2$ to get the mean and variance of $\bar{X}$.

Comment: Because $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\dots+X_n)$, whereas $\bar{X}\not=X_1 + \dots + X_n$.

Comment: Ok, to get the mean and the standard deviation i multiply by $\frac{1}{n}$,
but, why do i multiply by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ to get the variance ?

Comment: @Noam: The fact that the sample mean has standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, much smaller than $\sigma$ if $n$ is large, is what accounts for the usefulness of using a large sample when we want to estimate the true population mean.

Comment: @Noam: There is the general result that the variance of $kY$ is $k^2$ times the variance of $Y$. This comes out fairly quickly from the fact that the variance of $W$ is $E(W^2)-(E(W))^2$.

Comment: If you want to avoid $\bar{X}$ (but you should not want to) then let the sum be $W$.  Then $W$ has mean $25\mu$ and variance $25\sigma^2$, so standard deviation $5(13.15)$. To find the probability that the average is $\gt 86$, find the probability that the sum is $\gt (25)(86)$. The familiar calculation now will give you the same answer as what we get if we work with $\bar{X}$.

Comment: @Noam: You are welcome. The general theme will come up again, often.